# Power BI incremental refresh of old updated data

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database, refresh

I'm trying to figure out if there a possibility to config incremental refresh for the old data which could be updated.

E.g. we have initial table data (Azure SQL DB as a source):

| audit_date | val | updated_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 10 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 20 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2020-12-20 00:00:00.000 | 30 | 2020-12-20 00:00:00.000 |

and incremental refresh properties as below (audit_date is non-changable filtered column):

[image]

After data is published and refreshed it reflects whole source data (Power BI Pro):

[image]

Then we update some val column value (updated_ts receives current datetime value) and get below rows on the source:

| audit_date | val | updated_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 10 | 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000 | **555** | **2020-12-24 13:01:02.000** |
| 2020-12-20 00:00:00.000 | 30 | 2020-12-20 00:00:00.000 |

After refresh we still see initial values:

[image]

Does it mean that incremental refresh does not catch changes of old data or my understanding is wrong? Perhaps there is another way exists for such data changes handling?

Comment: Do you have Power BI Premium and is this workspace running on it? If so you could build your own partitioning and incremental processing tool.

Comment: so far I have only Pro license

Answer (score 0):

You've limited your rows to refresh to the last 30 days according to the `audit_date` column. Thus the row in question outside of the scope you've set.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-incremental-refresh) makes a similar remark:

> **Filter date column updates**
>
> The filter on the date column is used to dynamically partition the data into ranges in the Power BI service. Incremental refresh isn't designed to support cases where the filtered date column is updated in the source system. An update is interpreted as an insertion and a deletion, not an actual update. If the deletion occurs in the historical range and not the incremental range, it won't get picked up. This can cause data refresh failures due to partition-key conflicts.

Comment: Thank you, Alexis, but basically I want to figure out if there some way to catch data for refreshing for old rows updated where incremental date column isn't changed as in my example. Seems it is not possible with my current data source design, right?

Comment: You could try using the `updated_ts` column for your date parameter maybe?

Comment: Since **updated_ts** is changed on every row update, using it as a parameter contradicts to the documentation statement: _Incremental refresh isn't designed to support cases where the filtered date column is updated in the source system_

Comment: Ok. It sounds like your setup just isn’t conducive to incremental updates then.

Comment: Yes, basically that's what I'm thinking about as well, just wanted to hear thoughts from others for my conviction. Thanks

Comment: If you set the refresh data as last 5 years. Then will that solve your problem? Power bi will create yearly partitions. Effectively it will refresh the respective year partition when it notices the modified date change for record in the partition.